# ArcPy: DDP Error in exporting only occurs with "SELECTED"

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I'm trying to use DDP (Data Driven Pages) and am running into a problem. I'm using  arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management to select a series of records, and then trying to use the ddp.exportToPDF(pdfddp, "SELECTED") but keep running into an error (below). It shouldn't be the select by attribute function as I run it in ArcMap and it runs correctly and I can see the selected features highlighted. Also, I can successfully use the ddp.exportToPDF(pdfddp, "CURRENT") but what I need is to be able to have a user select a series of features and have those be passed.

```
 mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\temp\\Graffiti_DM4.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
pdfddp="C:\\temp\\pdfddp1.pdf"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("C:\\temp\\test.lyr","NEW_SELECTION", '"Incident_Z" ='  + "'10002'")
ddp.exportToPDF(pdfddp, "SELECTED")
```

And here is the error

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\_mapping.py", line 446, in exportToPDF
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.exportToPDF(*gp_fixargs((out_pdf, page_range_type, page_range_string, multiple_files, resolution, image_quality, colorspace, compress_vectors, image_compression, picture_symbol, convert_markers, embed_fonts, layers_attributes, georef_info, jpeg_compression_quality, show_selection_symbology), True)))
AttributeError: PageLayoutObject: Error in exporting pages
```

As always, any help is EXTREMELY appreciated!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the "SELECTED" should be referring to the index/page features.  It looks like a feature from the test.lyr is selected and not a index/page feature.  I would try to use those selected features in test.lyr to do a SelectByLocation to fetch the index/page features that have incidences of interest.

Answer (score 1):

For once, I'll answer my own question!

It's not the exact answer to why the above doesn't work, but is a work around:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\temp\\Graffiti_DM4.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]

newlayer="C:\\temp\\newlayer.lyr"
newpointout="C:\\temp\\newpointout.shp"
newpointlayer="C:\\temp\\newpointlayer.lyr"
pdfddp="C:\\temp\\pdfddp1.pdf"
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages

arcpy.Select_analysis(newlayer, newpointout,"'ZIP' = '10004'")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(newpointout, newpointlayer)
ddp.exportToPDF(newpointlayer, "ALL")
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I figured out you need to add a for loop after the selection and then use the "current" value for exportToPDF

Code:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1 #true

#define path to map with map book already defined
map_path = r"X:\PROJECTS\StormWater\CityWorks_STORMDRAIN_BOOK.mxd"
#define output location
out_loc = r"X:\maps\StormDrainPDF\test"

#override the output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1 #true

#create ddp object
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages

#set the dataframe
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]

#get the inlets layer so code only export grids that have storm features
inlet_lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Inlet")[0]

#get the gridlayer
grid_lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "CityGrid")[0]


#select layer by location
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(grid_lyr, "INTERSECT", inlet_lyr)
#test with get count
mycount = arcpy.GetCount_management(grid_lyr).getOutput(0)
print mycount

for indexPage in ddp.selectedPages:
    ddp.currentPageID =indexPage
    page_name = ddp.pageRow.GRID_ID
    #export to pdf
    out_pdf = os.path.join(out_loc, "Ebook_"+ page_name + ".pdf")
    ddp.exportToPDF(out_pdf, "CURRENT")

del mxd
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange and thanks for your contribution.  Please visit the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what consitutes a good answer.  You've posted a lot of unnecessary code in your answer.  Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/220326/edit) your post to only show the relevant bits of code and explain why this is a good solution.